# Parse Json to Primative Array Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, gson, android

Maybe this is simple, but I'm missing how to do this. I'm using GSON, kotlin, and retrofit

*Data.json*

```
{
  "array1":[1,2],
  "array2":[1,2]
}
```

*DataObject.kt*

```
data class DataObject(array1: List<Int>, array2: List<Int>)
```

The the above fails to deserialize the arrays.

Comment: Considering the kotlin code you've provided is not valid and wouldnt compile, I don't see how this code would even get to the deserialization step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a running example:

```
data class DataObject(val array1: List<Int>, val array2: List<Int>)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val json = """{"array1":[1,2],"array2":[1,2]}"""
    println(Gson().fromJson(json, DataObject::class.java))
    //DataObject(array1=[1, 2], array2=[1, 2])
}
```

I've only changed the arguments of `DataObject` to be `val`, which is required for data classes (`var` also works).

Comment: The properties of a `data class` may also be `var`.